# How to fire JavaScript pixel on click

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to get a Javascript pixel

```
<script language='JavaScript1.1' src='http://pixel.tag.com/event/js?mt_id=123456789&mt_adid=123456&v1=&v2=&v3=&s1=&s2=&s3='></script>
```

to fire *after* the click of a submit button similar to what you can find on this [page](http://www.keplergrp.com/contact/). (I know this might require building a simple "thank you" page, which is okay, but the pixel can't fire onClick.

Additionally, I would need the text from the different fields passed in to the v1, v2, etc. variables to be captured by the pixel.

```
<p>First Name <span class="orng">*</span><br />
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap first-name"><input type="text" name="first-name" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40" /></span> </p>
```

I am a bit new to this and am not a developer, but understand how it works conceptually so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `Oops! Google Chrome could not find pixel.tag.com`

Comment: JS pixel = javascript

Comment: @user2288602 That still makes no sense...

Comment: What doesn't make sense?

Comment: @user2288602 What is a "JavaScript pixel"? This phrase is ambiguous, and needs further explanation.

Comment: @elevine JS "pixel" is a misnomer, but one which marketing departments come by honestly.  These used to be 1px x 1px .gif requests made to analytics solutions, which would use the image as an end-point, and collect the values of predefined query-parameters, to do stat-tracking (ie: `tag.com/img.gif?prod_id=1234&qty=2&profit=32.45`). These are CORS workarounds circa 1998, using GET requests for `<img>` or `<script>` tags. As you might assume, "tracking pixel" has been the marketing-term to compress the gap between technical and non, much as "deeplinking" denotes a URI whose path isn't `/`

Comment: @AndersonGreen to further extrapolate: this process can still be very primitive (`<img src="//tag.com/track.gif?param1=1">`), or can be quite complex, such as Google Analytics, whose "snippet" is an inline script, which dynamically builds a script tag, whose `src` points at a Google-hosted JS application, which captures all sorts of client-machine information, business-defined metrics, captures values in cookies for persistance, and intelligently fires multiple .gif requests (without appending to DOM), based on URI-length. They are now also using POST requests, where CORS is supported in XHR2.

Answer (score 3):

From working with pixels before, here's what I'd recommend as a broad solution. Start off with a JavaScript String variable that's collecting the appropriate information to go along with ?mt_id=123456789&mt_adid=123456&v1=&v2=&v3=&s1=&s2=&s3=. If you already have that built, great.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var track = new Image();
    track.src="http://pixel.tag.com/event/js?self=" + dataString;
</script>
```

If it would be helpful to see another example of someone working through the same problem. Try reading through [this forum post](http://forums.site-reference.com/topic/6378/Javascript-Tracking-Pixel/).

Comment: Sorry, still not quite following. Why can't I set the v1=&v2=&v3=&s1=&s2=&s3= variables equal to the variable name of what is collected in the form? i.e `v1="first-name"&v2="last-name"&v3=&s1=&s2=&s3`

Comment: You can. As you gather the variables, append them to the string. For example, when you set var firstName="John Doe" make sure to append it to the query string. So.. something like queryString = queryString + "&v1=" + firstName

Answer (score 2):

The trick here isn't in the "tracking pixel", but rather, is in populating the values of the parameters.

The issue you're going to have here is that you're now going to have to build a string, which points to the .js file, and then build the parameters and values into strings, concatenate them all, build a script tag and point the url at your built values, so an ugly (by JS-purist standards) solution might look like this:

```
<form id="ContactForm">
    <input name="first-name">
    <input name="last-name">
    <button id="my-button" type="submit">sign up</button>
</form>

<script>

    // the button you want to listen to
var button = document.getElementById("my-button"),
    // assuming your form has the id "ContactForm"
    contact = window.ContactForm,

    // create a <script> tag, like the one that's hard-coded now
    script = document.createElement("script"),
    // find whatever element contains the first <script> on the page -- usually <head> or <body>
    parent = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],

    // as much of the tracking URL that you know will NEVER change
    url = "//analytics.tag.com/event/tracking.js?mt_id=123456&mt_adid=123abc";


button.onclick = function () {

    var full_url = "",
        v1,
        v2;

    v1 = contact["first-name"];
    v2 = contact["last-name"];

    full_url = url + "&v1=" + v1 + "&v2=" + v2;

    script.src = full_url;
    parent.appendChild(script);

};

</script>
```

When the button is clicked, the values will be collected from the form, they'll be added to the URL, and the script will be added to the page.

Here's the next problem:

If this is a  and you're capturing a click which takes you to the next page, by default, then you have to cancel the form-submission, otherwise, the request for the JS file is going to be ignored (why load new stuff when you told the browser you want to go to the next page?).

So then you need to modify the `button.onclick` to be something like:

```
button.onclick = function (e) {
    // IE < 9 supports "window.event", instead of an event-object as a parameter
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        // IE < 9
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue  = false;
    }


    /*  DO ALL OF YOUR DATA-COLLECTION AND STRING-BUILDING HERE
        ie: most of the first version of this function (all before `script.src =...`)
     */


    // after the script loads, fire contact.submit
    script.onload = contact.submit;
    // if the script errors out (404/etc) fire contact.submit
    script.onerror = contact.submit;
    // GhettoIE fix, for when scripts don't support "onload"
    script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (script.readyState === 4) { contact.submit(); }
    };

    /* SET THE SCRIPT URL HERE */
    script.src = full_url;
    parent.appendChild(script);
};
```

Now when you click the button, it will prevent the form from submitting (taking you to the next page) until you collect all of the form values, stuff them into the URL for the script, putting the script on the page, and waiting for the server to get the request and respond.

This is done in a very, very ugly cross-browser (IE6+/Safari3+) compatible format.
If you've got a decent JS guy there, get him to do better than this, or I'll cry...

If you need to collect the data on the next page (say you need to calculate your actual profit on the sale, after the server processes payment), you're better off doing this in the server's language:

```
// php
"<script src=\"....?v1=$profit&v2=$product_id\"></script>";
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I feel like this is getting hairier than necessary. Why can't I just take the variables from the form, which I pulled from inspecting the page elements, and pass those into the pixel like so...`v1=&v2=&v3=&s1=&s2=&s3=` variables equal to the variable name of what is collected in the form? i.e `v1="first-name"&v2="last-name"&v3=&s1=&s2=&s3`

Comment: @user2288602 That's exactly what my code does. And you can't do it while leaving the `<script>` tag hard-coded in the HTML because it fires ***AS SOON AS THE BROWSER READS THAT LINE OF HTML*** so you either need to write it programmatically, using JavaScript (see my code above), or you need to pre-fill the fields on the page, using PHP, or whatever server language you're going to use.  In the case of fields which rely on user-input, that means that you need to put this tag on the ***NEXT PAGE*** and fill the values in, using your server-language and form-results, so that the HTML is complete.

Comment: @user2288602 HTML and JavaScript are two different languages, and one won't understand the other...  ...so if your HTML looks like: `<script src="//page.com/img.gif?v1='first-name'"></script>` that's EXACTLY what you'll see in your report. If you write `v1=window.MyForm["first-name"]`, then the server that gets the response will see `$v1 = "window.MyForm[\"first-name\"]";` as an exact value. Because HTML doesn't run JavaScript...  So you have to wait for the button to be clicked, collect the values from the form, build the string like `"//www...?" + "v1=" + val_1 + "..."` and buid it yourself.

Comment: @user2288602 It gets extra-hairy because you want to fire a call when you're submitting data, where that submission causes the next page to load. When you ask the next page to load, it ignores ALL unfinished downloads and moves to the next page. So you have to stop the form, send the request, wait for it to come back, and then submit the form. If it wasn't a form, and you wanted to know how many people clicked "play", then the answer is easier. And like I said, for actual JS-devs, there are cleaner ways of doing this. My answer is just a quick'n'dirty library-free solution that will work.

Comment: PS: this has been my day-job for the past ~2 years. Custom-tracking for PPC/Analytics has been a very big deal at my company. I've even written code-recommendations/reviews for the product managers at Adobe, regarding their tracking-programs for PPC/Analytics. Fun times.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, and I think I'm starting to wrap my head around it a bit more. Assuming I can fire the pixel on button click instead of page load, how much easier would this be?

Comment: @user2288602 That depends on what the button *does* when it's clicked on. If the button submits the form, then it's all of the work seen above. If you have a "thank-you"/receipt page that loads after the current page, and you have a programmer who did the work for putting in the forms in the first place, then putting the pixel on the "thank-you" page, the way you have it, originally, but with all of the values filled in by the programmer (with values that would be going in the database, before loading the next page) would be more straightforward.  AND would be better for validation purposes.

Comment: @user2288602 the reason I say it would be better for validation purposes is: if you add it to the thank-you page, and the thank-you page ONLY shows up if the form was filled out properly, and the data was properly added to your database, then sending the affiliate data (which I'm assuming you pay for) on a successful booking/sign-up/etc would be the only time it fired.  Firing "onclick" means that first you have to make sure that the form is valid (so that you're sure it will be successful), otherwise, you might be paying for unsuccessful attempts. This is where being technical is important.